# How do I make database table entries from another class?

Tags: java, database, sqlite, methods

I am struggling with sqlite crud actions in a class other than the database class. It just occurred to me that any CRUD actions need to happen in the database class and I call those parameterized functions from the calling class. I have tried to use the sqlite functionality from another class but cannot seem to get the environment set up correctly. This other class cannot seem to connect to the database. In this other class I have a list that I want to fill with records that I read. I can not get the crud actions to compile. Should I fill the list in a public method in the database class and pass the list back to the calling class? And how would I do crud actions from a non database class using a database set up in a database class? I thought this was a passig context action but that attempt appears that I am incorrect in my approach. Any help would keep me from any more angst over this mindset issue. I know it is nothing more than 'I am missing something'.

Comment: I would like to add that all the examples I see are single class answers. The java environment is made up of many classes, those inherent and created. I very rarely see examples using multiple java files/classes pertaining to this type of issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I followed another post that specified having a class for each table then using an import in the current activity.